# Application getting purged by Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I start my Android app, which in turns initializes some state on the first screen. The app has a many screens, and after randomly navigating through some screens, I minimize the app using the "Home key". Now after running some other apps from the phone, the OS decides that it needs to free up my app and hence kills it.

Now when I again click on the app icon, the OS remembers the history and tries to go back to the screen from where I minimized the app. But, the problem is since the OS purged my app sometime back, all my states are lost and the screen may not have any relevance.

How do I tackle this? How do I ensure that the OS calls the launcher screen, if it has been purged before and not the Activity in the history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your above comment about singleton class being initialized I also faced situations similar to you. Since I could not avoid it, what I did was I used the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. Whenever the OS decides to purge your app, the next time you launch the app, `onCreate` on the `Application class` will be called. Override the `onCreate` method to initialize the singleton class rather than doing the same in the launcher screen

The code snippet is as follows

```
public class CellApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Do your singleton class initialization here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a snippet on how to do this? The documentation itself seems insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You don't make sure the OS calls the launcher screen. The best way to solve this problem ist to save the state of your screens.

Everytime one of your activities is put in background [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) is called. This allows you to save the state of your app to the bundle that is provided in this method. If your app resumes onCreate will be called with the exact same bundle. You can now rebuild the app the same state the user left it.

Just check if the the bundle in onCreate is null. If it is null your activity is new if not rebuild the state from the bundle.

Comment: My situation is not as simple as that. I have a huge singleton class being instantiated on the launcher screen, which is used by the entire app. Now when I app starts from a random screen instead of Launcher screen, this singleton is not initialized. and things go for a toss.

Comment: Maybe you have to think about this singleton practice ;) You can finish every activity in the onCreate method if the singleton is not available. That should bring the user back to the launcher screen because your statck of created activities will close down.

Comment: That would make it cumbersome. There are quite a lot more tangles which makes it practically impossible.